# Motorcycle fuel tank inspection procedures?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system

All of a sudden cylinders 3 and 4 won't fire.  The only single thing in common is the fuel feed.  Suspecting perhaps some debris (rust?) in the tank that found its way down into the 3/4 fuel tee between the carbs.  The fuel feed off the petcock for 3/4 is pretty much the lowest point in the tank (lower slightly than the feed for 1/2).

How do I go about inspecting the inside of the tank for rust?  What tools/procedures should be followed?  I'd like to be thorough and not causing an explosion is a plus.  Is it required to dump all the fuel first?  If so, can I strain/filter it for re-use later?

Comment: Dump the fuel. Don't reuse it (at least for automotive fuel ... molotov cocktails are okay ;-). Use an [**inspection camera**](https://www.amazon.com/Depstech-Semi-rigid-Inspection-Waterproof-Adjustable/dp/B06VXPVWXG/) to see about the rust.

Comment: Also if you drain some gas (a couple cups is fine) via the petcock that will pull any potential debris to the bottom. Then removing the petcock will show rust if there is a large amount.